# My bouquet of roses has green leafs. Can I plant them?

Tags: roses

[image]

So I got these for my birthday and they have lasted about a month. I’ve noticed the green leafs and would like to replant them. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The new growth does suggest there is some life left in those cuttings. Many roses grow readily from semi-ripe and hardwood cuttings. Why not give it a go? It is a long shot to use stems that have just flowered, but you might get some free plants out of it.

They'll need tidying up first. If the stems have gone soft in the area submerged, remove the soft bit. Next, remove any flowers and flower buds. You are aiming to produce a cutting that has a couple of nodes (leaves removed if present) below the level of the compost to produce roots and a couple above the level of the compost to produce new shoots. Remove all bar one leaf per cutting (starting with the old leaves) - too many leaves will cause the cutting to lose water too quickly. Then insert into a free draining compost mix - John Innes no. 1 or similar. Don't let them get too hot, indirect light will be best. Don't forget to water them but don't sit them in a deep tray of water or they will rot. Protect from frost - be aware that a lot of roses sold as cut flower markets are produced in warmer climes (than the UK where I am) and are bred for those conditions.

Comment: Awesome. I still have them in a vase. They are dry but smell good and the green is growing. I’ll do that and keep them indoors in a smaller plant. If they catch, I’ll move them to the back yard.